# Render Html view as Word document

Tags: httpcontext

Below code converts returns an MVC view as a Word document, but it doesn't give the downloaded file a `.doc` extension.

```
public ActionResult ToWord()
{
    var model = Logic.GetModel();
    string html = Utils.ViewToString(this, "MyView", model);
    return Content(html, "application/msword");
}

static string ViewToString(Controller controller, string viewName, object model)
{
    controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, viewResult.View, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

I have tried adding below code, but the extension appears to be ignored. Saving the document as `file.doc` makes Word behave correctly:

```
HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "wordFile.doc");
```

Any ideas how I can get extension added to the file?

Comment: HTML is not a `.doc` file.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I agree with comment above. The code you have written doesn't convert your page to a word doc, it simply instructs the browser to display your html in Word. So, naming the downloaded with a .doc extension may cause weirdness. IDK, haven't tried.

That being said, I think you're looking for the filename property of the content-disposition header:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=whatever.doc");
```

Comment: As mentioned in question I have already said Response.AddHeader doesn't work. I know this doesn't convert the document I just wanted to set the file name.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been said, you should not return html as .doc unless you have converted said html.

However, what you are looking for is a `FileStreamResult` to return.

Replace:

```
return Content(html, "application/msword");
```

With:

```
return File(htmlStream, "application/msword", Server.UrlEncode("filename.doc"));
```

You can generate a MemoryStream from a string with the following code:

```
MemoryStream htmlStream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(htmlStream);
writer.Write(html);
writer.Flush();
htmlStream.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a bit more than just save HTML with a *.doc extension.

To go from HTML to a Word *.docx file you can use the "altChunk" technique described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/27/how-to-use-altchunk-for-document-assembly.aspx. Bear in mind that the HTML formatting and CSS styling you can use is slightly limited, but if you work within these constraints it can work quite well.

Also, you need to set the `Content-Disposition` header correctly, e.g.:  `"attachment; filename=whatever.doc"`. Bear in mind that the filename can be problematic for certain browsers if it includes special characters so it's best to use MVC's support for this by returning a `FileResult` with the `FileDownloadName` set, like so:

```
return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(html), "application/msword", "My File Name.doc");
```

Comment: As mentioned in question I have already said Response.AddHeader doesn't work. I know this doesn't convert the document I just wanted to set the file name

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem was just because the ".doc" extension got truncated. The key is the filename=\"" + strFileName + "\";"); These two lines work for me.

string strFileName = "Staff Report" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + ".doc";

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + strFileName + "\";");

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  I don't think the issue is actually about the extension, I think they are corrupting a html / doc file.  Anyway, perhaps if you add some context that relates to the actual problem - you could be on a winner with this answer a little improved